# replace nan in one column with the value from another column in pandas: what's wrong with my code

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I need to replace the nan in column a with the corresponding value from column b in the same row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   'b': [4,5,6,7,8,9,1]})
df['a'] =df.apply(lambda row: row['b'] if row['a'].isnull() else row['a'] )
```

I got error:

```
KeyError: ('a', 'occurred at index a')
```

what did I do wrong in the code? I could not figure why it did not work after think about it for long time. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `axis=1`, also, youll have to use `pd.isnull(row['a'])`:

```
In [6]: df.apply(lambda row: row['b'] if pd.isnull(row['a']) else row['a'], axis=1)
Out[6]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    8.0
5    9.0
6    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Although, you shouldn't be using `.apply` in the first place, use `fillna`:

```
In [9]: df.a.fillna(df.b)
Out[9]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    8.0
5    9.0
6    5.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

More generally, for any predicate, use `pd.Series.where`:

```
In [32]: df.a.where(pd.notnull, df.b)
Out[32]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    8.0
5    9.0
6    5.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass index=1 to operate on rows. This code here works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   'b': [4,5,6,7,8,9,1]})

df['a'] =df.apply(lambda row: row['b'] if pd.isnull(row['a']) else row['a'], axis=1)

df
```

Comment: `np.nan != np.nan`, this won't work, you'll have to use `pd.isnull(...)` or `math.isnan(...)`